# Declaring and Setting Form Variable in Access VBA

Tags: ms-access, vba

It seems so simple, but I can't seem to find the correct syntax.  I am looking to create a form variable for an unopened form in my Access 2013 application so I can pass the form object to a series of methods rather than passing separate properties of the form.

Here's what I've been attempting, but I run into Run-time error '2465' "Microsoft Access can't find the field 'frmSuppliers' referenced in your expression.

```
Private Sub cmdSuppliers_Click()
    Dim frm As Form
    Set frm = Form("frmSuppliers")

    Debug.Print frm.Name
```

Comment: You have to open the form for it to be initialized and added to the forms collection of the DB

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thank you Sorceri and Christopher.  I seem to have been missing a compilation of the wrong reference to the forms collection and not opening the form prior to setting the variable.  This code seems to do the trick:

```
Private Sub cmdSuppliers_Click()
    Dim frm As Form

    DoCmd.OpenForm "frmSuppliers", acNormal, , , , acHidden
    Set frm = Forms("frmSuppliers")

    Debug.Print frm.Name

    DoCmd.Close acForm, frm.Name
    Set frm = Nothing

End Sub
```

Answer (score 5):

```
Private Sub cmdSuppliers_Click()
    Dim frm As Form
    Set frm = Forms("frmSuppliers")

    Debug.Print frm.Name
```

You referenced the Forms collection but made it singular instead of plural.